# htacess seems to make the page load forever

Tags: web-hosting, php, htaccess

I need to rewrite a URL of my server so the URL looks friendly. Like:

`site.com/var1/var2/var3/...`

to

`site.com/index.php?page=var1/var2/var3/...`

So I wrote this .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

But when I upload it to the server, and try to load a page, the page loads forever! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also note that `.htaccess` has 2 `c`s - just in case that isn't a typo in the question! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will result in a rewrite loop. You are also not capturing the sub pattern, so `$1` will be empty. In order to prevent a rewrite loop, you need a get-out-clause, such as not rewriting when the request is already for `index.php`.

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Only when the request is *not* for `/index.php` will the `RewriteRule` be processed. The parenthesised sub pattern `(.*)` is stored in `$1`.

Comment: I tested this by echo-ing $_GET["page"]; and I always get 'index.php'. What's happening? No matter what I type in it, I always get the index.php.

Comment: I wanted to type like: site.com/page1/page2/page3 and rewrite to index.php?page=page1/page2/page3

Comment: I've just corrected the `RewriteRule` substitution by prefixing this with a `/` to make it root-relative. However, it should have still worked from the document root. Yes, this code rewrites `site.com/page1/page2/page3` to `/index.php?page=page1/page2/page3` (in the document root).

Comment: I want all this to ocurr in my test directory named v3, does I need to make the condition to be !=/v3/index.php? I want the index.php?page=... to be on the same root, so I don't need the slahes in it.

Comment: Yes, if this is all happening in a subdirectory then that directory will need to be prefixed to the `REQUEST_URI` condition and omit the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` substitution. (The subdirectory is automatically removed when matching against the `RewriteRule` pattern.)

Comment: Well, thank you so much, but I've tested the code and it keeps receiving only 'index.php' in the page variable :(. The rewriting is working: it redirect to the page I want, but the variable sent isn't working.

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Presumably something like: `site.com/v3/page1/page2` ?

Comment: Yep, when I do this, it redirects to index.php but the variable received when I GET 'page' is always 'index.php'

Comment: Well, either it's not rewriting to the URL you think it is OR there is some error in your PHP code that is resulting in the wrong value being output?

Comment: I rewritten now to a page called 'rec.php' just to test, this page is <?php
$string  = $_GET["page"];
echo 'this: '.$string.' end<p>';
?> and what I'm gettin is exactly 'this rec.php end'

Comment: Have you tried a different URL parameter?

Comment: Yep, I tried different ones, no parameter, lots of parameters, other .php page, etc... :c